# How do I completely restart my python script from within?

Tags: python

I'm creating a little calculator as a project And I want it to restart when it type yes when it's done. Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how. I'm not a whiz when it comes to python.

```
   import sys

    OPTIONS = ["Divide", "divide", "Multiply", "multiply", "Add", "add", "Subtract", "subtract"]

    def userinput():
        while True:
            try:

                number = int(input("Number: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("NOPE...")
        return number

    def operation():
        while True:
            operation = input("Multiply/Divide/Add: ")
            if operation in OPTIONS:
                break
            else:
                print("Not an option.")
        return operation

    def playagain():
        while True:
            again = input("Again? Yes/No: ")
            if again == "Yes" or again == "yes":
                 break
            elif again == "No" or again == "no":
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                print("Nope..")

    def multiply(x,y):
        z = x * y
        print(z)

    def divide(x,y):
        z = x / y
        print(z)

    def add(x,y):
        z = x + y
        print(z)

    def subtract(x,y):
        z = x - y
        print(z)

    while True:

        operation = operation()
        x = userinput()
        y = userinput()
        if operation == "add" or operation == "Add":
            add(x,y)
        elif operation == "divide" or operation == "Divide":
            divide(x,y)
        elif operation == "multiply" or operation == "Multiply":
            multiply(x,y)
        elif operation == "subtract" or operation == "Subtract":
            subtract(x,y)

        playagain()
```

I currently have a break in line 28 because I can't find out how to restart it. If anyone could help me, THANKS!

Comment: Please put a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not a link to all of your code somewhere else.

Comment: Meanwhile, usually the answer is: just wrap up all the top-level code inside a function, and then just call that function in a `while True:` loop. That doesn't work in some cases (e.g., if you've got a bunch of tangled-up global state), but try it and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new. How do i do that? I do have this. def playagain():
    while True:
        again = input("Again? Yes/No: ")
        if again == "Yes" or again == "yes":
             break
        elif again == "No" or again == "no":
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print("Nope..")

Comment: And like i said, I'm no whiz. So i really have next to no knowledge as to what you just said. I'm learning fast though :D

Comment: Edit your question to include a minimal, complete, verifiable example, and we can show you how to wrap it up so that it restarts itself. If you don't give us that, all you can get are vague answers.

Comment: Click the link in my first comment and it will tell you what a minimal, complete example should look like. Write one, and make sure to test it and verify that it really does what you say it does. Then click the "edit" button under your question, paste your code into the question, select it, and click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said. It's a rather short program.

Comment: @NicholasClem 'rather short': perfect.

Comment: Note that you have a bug in your code around `operation = operation()`, see my post.

Comment: As a side note, you can just `return number` from the middle of the look in `userinput`—or even just `return int(input(…))` without storing it, because you don't use the local variable anywhere else—instead of doing a `break` just to get to a `return`.

Comment: As another side note, if you know about dictionaries, you can put functions in a dictionary, like [this](http://pastebin.com/jrPsYj83). Or even get tricky like [this](http://pastebin.com/nPKSumT2).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to restart your script, just have a little bit of thought about the design before you code.  Taking the script you provided, there are two alterations for this issue:

```
def playagain():

    while True:
        again = input("Again? Yes/No: ")
        if again == "Yes" or again == "yes":
             return True
        elif again == "No" or again == "no":
             return False
        else:
            print("Nope..")
```

Then, where you call `playagain()`, change that to:

```
if not playagain(): break
```

I think I know why you want to restart the script, you have a bug.

Python functions are like any other object.  When you say:

```
operation = operation()
```

that reassigns the reference to the `operation` function to the string returned by the function.  So the second time you call it on restart it fails with:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

RENAME your `operation` function something like `foperation`:

```
def fopertion():
```

then:

```
operation = foperation()
```

So, the complete code becomes:

```
import sys

OPTIONS = ["Divide", "divide", "Multiply", "multiply", "Add", "add", "Subtract", "subtract"]

def userinput():
    while True:
        try:

            number = int(input("Number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("NOPE...")
    return number

def foperation():
    while True:
        operation = input("Multiply/Divide/Add: ")
        if operation in OPTIONS:
            break
        else:
            print("Not an option.")
    return operation


def playagain():

    while True:
        again = input("Again? Yes/No: ")
        if again == "Yes" or again == "yes":
             return True
        elif again == "No" or again == "no":
             return False
        else:
            print("Nope..")

def multiply(x,y):
    z = x * y
    print(z)

def divide(x,y):
    z = x / y
    print(z)

def add(x,y):
    z = x + y
    print(z)

def subtract(x,y):
    z = x - y
    print(z)

while True:

    operation = foperation()
    x = userinput()
    y = userinput()
    if operation == "add" or operation == "Add":
        add(x,y)
    elif operation == "divide" or operation == "Divide":
        divide(x,y)
    elif operation == "multiply" or operation == "Multiply":
        multiply(x,y)
    elif operation == "subtract" or operation == "Subtract":
        subtract(x,y)

    if not playagain(): break
```

There are many other improvements to this code that I could make, but let's just get this working first.

Answer (score 0):

instead of restarting the scrip i made it so you could use it forever and only the user himself can exit it. i only changed the playagain() and the while loop at the end, read the comments for the explanation:

```
import sys

OPTIONS = ["Divide", "divide", "Multiply", "multiply", "Add", "add", "Subtract", "subtract"]

# python2 compatibility, you dont need to care about this ;-)
try:
    input = raw_input
except:
    pass

def userinput():
    while True:
        try:

            number = int(input("Number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("NOPE...")
    return number

def operation():
    while True:
        operation = input("Multiply/Divide/Add: ")
        if operation in OPTIONS:
            break
        else:
            print("Not an option.")
    return operation

def playagain():
    """
    return True if userinput "Yes" and False if userinput "no"
    does this until user input is yes or no
    """
    again = input("Again? Yes/No: ")
    if again.lower() == "yes":
        return True
    elif again.lower() == "no":
        return False
    else:
        # reruns the code --> until user input is 'yes' or 'no'
        return playagain()

def multiply(x,y):
    z = x * y
    print(z)

def divide(x,y):
    z = x / y
    print(z)

def add(x,y):
    z = x + y
    print(z)

def subtract(x,y):
    z = x - y
    print(z)

# a main in python: this will be executed when run as a script
# but not when you import something from this
if __name__ == '__main__':

    play = True
    while play:
        operation = operation()
        x = userinput()
        y = userinput()
        if operation == "add" or operation == "Add":
            add(x,y)
        elif operation == "divide" or operation == "Divide":
            divide(x,y)
        elif operation == "multiply" or operation == "Multiply":
            multiply(x,y)
        elif operation == "subtract" or operation == "Subtract":
            subtract(x,y)

        # player/user can exit the loop if he enters "no" and therefore end the loop
        play = playagain()
```

Answer (score -3):

Use os.execv()....

[Restarting a Python Script Within Itself](http://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/03/23/restarting-a-python-script-within-itself/)

Comment: It says it doesn't match any "Indentation" Level.